# How to find HTML element with a data attribute which contains a specific value?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using data attributes in HTML and now I want to get it.

I have attribute like this:

```
<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="3,4">
```

Suppose I have a value "3". I want to search for the data attribute that contains "3";

How can I do this?

Comment: You should use space to seperate values, not comma, then you could just use as selector `'[data-party-registration-source-type-id~="3"]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with jQuery attribute contains selector that:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing a given substring.

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

> This is the most generous of the jQuery attribute selectors that match
>   against a value. It will select an element if the selector's string
>   appears anywhere within the element's attribute value.

example:

```
  $( "div.row[data-party-registration-source-type-id*='3']" )
```

Comment: No you cannot in this case. It won't be specific to only `3` but anything containing `3` like e.g `13`

Comment: Happy to hear @CodeLover, if so- an upvote will be very appreciated :-)

Comment: @RonenCypis i am new at this site and have no privilege to up-vote. When reached at 15. I will vote your answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff that's consistent with the question though - it didn't specify anything about checking whole, comma-separated numbers, just that the data attribute "contains" the search item.

Comment: But this answer work for me but when i add more item's and search 1, it brings 10 and 11 as well. So here is the solution i found.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007191/how-to-search-exact-contain-value-by-jquery-wild-card-for-data-attribute/36007905?noredirect=1#comment59668378_36007905

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `dataset` in javascript to fetch the data that is relevant to your `data-attribute`, split it and check it,

```
var isExist = document
               .querySelector("div.row.hidden")
                   .dataset.partyRegistrationSourceTypeId.split(",").indexOf("3") > -1
```

Comment: But `querySelector()` returns only one node

Comment: Then use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @A.Wolff Yeah, Just given a sample for OP. Thought he would extend it as per his requirement. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I don't think he would extend anything judging by the quality of his question but anyway i gave you credit for this answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try with the contains selector:

```
$('[data-party-registration-source-type-id~="3"]')
```

Comment: Its a white space separated list of words. This, like mine, won't work with he OP's comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
This won't work for the OP's data-set of numbers. It will return elements that contain `33` if searching for `3` for example.

---

You can use the CSS Selector wildcard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

It is native so you can use ti with or without jquery.

```
$('[data-party-registration-source-type-id*="3"]');

document.querySelectorAll('[data-party-registration-source-type-id*="3"]');
```

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qw1x0eo7/

Comment: It will return the elements if the attribute has 33 also.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Ahh yes your right, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Single Test Input Div on page,
Firstly, get data attribute string and break into array with the help of split function.

```
attrName = 'data-party-registration-source-type-id';

dataArray = $('['+attrName+']').attr(attrName).split(",");
```

Then, trim array value to remove any white space and praseInt to convert character into int.

```
 trimmedDataArray = $.map(dataArray, function(value) {
  return parseInt(value.trim());
 });

testVal = 3;
isExist = $.inArray( testVal, trimmedDataArray );
```

If, "isExist" = -1 (not found)
Else,  (found)

For Multiple Test Input Div on page,

Use above code in with each function

```
attrName = 'data-party-registration-source-type-id';
testValArray = [3,4,5,6];
$('['+attrName+']').each(function(index){
     dataArray = '';
     dataArray = $(this).attr(attrName).split(",");
      trimmedDataArray = $.map(dataArray, function(value) {
         return parseInt(value.trim()); // for words use, return value.trim();
      });

     testVal = testValArray[index];
     isExist = $.inArray( testVal, trimmedDataArray );
     //your code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in this thread because I was facing the same issue, but most of answers are advising of doing something like:

```
$( "div.row[data-party-registration-source-type-id*='3']" )
```

The main issue with this is, if you have for example an element like `<div class="row" data-party-registration-source-type-id="03">` with data attribute "03" or "333" or "13" etc... all these will match

The only way I can find to make the exact match is by adding a delimiter to the data attribute value:

```
<div class="row" data-party-registration-source-type-id="|3|">
```

Then test against it using:

```
$( "div.row[data-party-registration-source-type-id*='|3|']" )
```

Surely enough, it works with multiple comma separated data attribues as well, i.e:

```
<div class="row" data-party-registration-source-type-id="|3|, |7|, |11|, |..|">
```

Note: The delimiter `||` could be anything else from your choise.