# How to search exact contain value by jquery wild card for data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using data_attribute in the page and i have followings element with data attribute.

```
No. 1.<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="1">
    2.<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="2,3">
    3.<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="3">
    4.<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="4,5">
    5.<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="11">
    6.<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="10">
```

Now i want to show all div that have data-party-registration-source-type-id =3
It will show No.2 and 3. I am using this to search

```
var partyRegistrationSourceId = $partyRegistrationSourceTypes.val();

 $('[data-party-registration-source-type-id*=' + partyRegistrationSourceId + ']').removeClass("hidden");
```

It is working fine, now the problem is, when i want to search with id "1", it brings number 1,5,6. Every id that contains 1, it bring it. I only want with the id 1. How i can do this? if i use this:

```
$('[data-party-registration-source-type-id=' + partyRegistrationSourceId + ']').removeClass("hidden");
```

Then it will work in this case but not working in above case. How i can search all id that contains exact id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try adding kind of separators for each key:

```
<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="{1}">
<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="{2},{3}">
<div class="row hidden" data-party-registration-source-type-id="{3}">

var partyRegistrationSourceId = $partyRegistrationSourceTypes.val();

$("[data-party-registration-source-type-id*='{" + partyRegistrationSourceId + "}']").removeClass("hidden");
```

Let me know if suits your problem or is not what you need

Comment: Thanks for reply, Let me try

Comment: where is failing? did you copy exactly the same code? i did modify some ' by "

Comment: It works actually. I was using single quote. With double quote, it's working. Thanks but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: maybe you could use some regular expression on the data attribute but maybe is less readable

Comment: ok. I will post here if i find any other way. Thanks again for help.