# Check whether elements contain particular dataset item

Tags: javascript

I want to create a filter for some projects. When a user selects a tag the related projects are logged.

I believe the below doesn't work because of the spaces between the `[data-tags]` items. I can't change this so the filter has to be resilient to this. How can I go about this?

```js
function filterTag() {
    const tags = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.filter-tags li'));

    tags.forEach((tag) => {
        tag.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const selectedTag = this.dataset.tag
            const relatedProjects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tags=${selectedTag}]`));

            console.log(relatedProjects)
        })
    })
}

filterTag();
```

```css
.filter-tags li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div[data-tags] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="filter-tags">
  <li data-tag="industrial">Industrial</li>
  <li data-tag="commercial">Commercial</li>
  <li data-tag="pavillion">Pavillion</li>
</ul>

<div data-tags="industrial commercial pavillion ">Project 1</div>
<div data-tags="industrial commercial pavillion ">Project 2</div>
<div data-tags="commercial ">Project 3</div>
<div data-tags="industrial ">Project 4</div>
<div data-tags="pavillion ">Project 5</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your attributes’ values are whitespace-separated lists, you can use the `[data-tags~=${selectedTag}]` selector:

```
const relatedProjects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[data-tags~=${selectedTag}]`));
```

The list of possible selectors is in the [CSSWG Selectors Overview](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview).

---

There’s a [related question for comma-separated lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35843753/4642212), though others recommend simply using a whitespace-separated list instead.